# Setting different recycler views different adapters both show the same

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have one activity which contains two recycler views. Each one has his own adapter with his own data. 
If I set just the first adapter, it shows it correctly. But when I set also de second adapter, both shows the data from the second. Anyone knows why could this happen?

```
    playersTeamOne = new ArrayList<>();
    playersTeamTwo = new ArrayList<>();

    LinearLayoutManager llm1 = new LinearLayoutManager(GameTeamsActivity.this);
    recyclerTeamOne.setLayoutManager(llm1);

    LinearLayoutManager llm2 = new LinearLayoutManager(GameTeamsActivity.this);
    recyclerTeamTwo.setLayoutManager(llm2);

    Player player = new Player();
    player.setFirstName("leila");
    player.setLastName("feiguin");
    player.setProfileImageUrl("hola");
    player.isCaptain = false;
    playersTeamOne.add(player);

    Player player2 = new Player();
    player2.setFirstName("jazmin");
    player2.setLastName("lopez");
    player2.setProfileImageUrl("hola");
    player2.isCaptain = true;
    playersTeamTwo.add(player2);

    GameTeamAdapter adapter1 = new GameTeamAdapter(playersTeamOne, GameTeamsActivity.this);
    recyclerTeamOne.setAdapter(adapter1);

    GameTeamAdapter adapter2 = new GameTeamAdapter(playersTeamTwo, GameTeamsActivity.this);
    recyclerTeamTwo.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

This is the xml UI which contains both recycler views:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background_app"
tools:context="com.wannaplaycorp.wannaplay.Activities.GameTeamsActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="11dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgClose"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_eliminar"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_wannaplay"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDownload"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_compartir"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp">

    <!-- team 1 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTeamOne"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camiseta_blanca"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerTeamOne"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_player_teams" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1.111dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" />

    <!-- team 2 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgTeamTwo"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camiseta_azul"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerTeamTwo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_player_teams" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @Rohit5k2 i did it

Comment: Post the part where you initialize your variables, also the Adapter.

Comment: Can you show the code where you have initialized `recyclerTeamOne` and `recyclerTeamTwo`